# Correct usage of async and awaitable objects inside class with Python 3.7

Tags: python, oop, asynchronous, python-3.7

Im trying to write class with methods to call awaitable objects but can't figure out how to do it right. The following code kinda works, but does not seem right as seen from the warning below.

```
class SmartThings():

    async def print_devices(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            api = pysmartthings.SmartThings(session, TOKEN)    
            devices = await api.devices()
            print(devices[0].name)

    def run(self):
        asyncio.run(self.print_devices())
```

So I create the instance and call the methods:

```
x = SmartThings()
x.print_devices()
x.run()
```

..which works (prints the desired output) but gives me a `RuntimeWarning` (probably when calling `x.print_devices()`)

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'SmartThings.print_devices' was never awaited
  x.print_devices()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost one-year-old question, but I've used this as starting point and I wanted to share the outcome. If you're looking for a working example to start with, here it is:

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import pysmartthings

# Token: https://account.smartthings.com/tokens
TOKEN = 'e54fde2b-f759-4234-b413-WHATEVER'

def main():

    st = SmartThings(TOKEN)
    devices = st.print_devices()
    
    for device in devices :
        print(device.name)


class SmartThings:
    def __init__(self, TOKEN):
        self.TOKEN = TOKEN

    # return devices
    async def search_devices(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            api = pysmartthings.SmartThings(session, self.TOKEN)
            devices = await api.devices()
            return devices

    def print_devices(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        devices = loop.run_until_complete(self.search_devices())
        loop.close()
    
        return devices

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```